# KONG on AWS Loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, kong

I have setup KONG on AWS using CloudFormation script provided on their website. Post installation i have a problem wherein I have done Route 53 routing(CNAME) of a domain to the load balancer.

But Kong always accepts 8000 port so i always have to call the ADDED API's in KONG as follows;

http://$AWS_LOAD_BALANCER_URL$:8000/api/student

I want to be able to access it like

http://$AWS_LOAD_BALANCER_URL$/api/student

I am new to AWS and KONG - so your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change Kong to listen on a different port. You can see an example here - https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/1127